# How to list sub directories of a directory?

Tags: bash

I need to list the sub directories of a certain path. The separation should be with spaces and not new lines.

I also do not want the absolute path to the sub directories, just their names.

```
# correct
dir1 dir2 dir3

# incorrect: separation with new lines
dir1
dir2
dir3

# incorrect: absolute paths
/home/x/y/dir1 /home/x/y/dir2 /home/x/y/dir3
```

I've seen a lot of other posts like [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168071/list-sub-directories-with-ls), but they do not accomplish my request.

I've tried `ls -d ~/y` but it lists absolute paths and separates with new lines. I guess I could use sed to remove the irrelevant part of the path, and then remove all the new lines. But I couldn't get it to work, and it seems like there should be a better solution

Comment: Also, a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/902710), since you don't explain why this has to be done via `ls` (as your question title indicates).  You seem to be presupposing that the solution needs to involve `ls`, but you don't explain why this can't or shouldn't be done via other means like `find`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using GNU tools, you could use GNU `basename` to get the names of all subdirectories in a particular directory.  You could then use `paste` to format this as a space-delimited list.

```bsh
basename -a /some/path/*/ | paste -d ' ' -s -
```

The above command uses the fact that GNU `basename` has an `-a` option to return the filename portion of multiple pathnames given as operands on its command line.

We use a file-globbing pattern ending in `/` to generate the pathnames for GNU `basename`.  Only directories can match such a pattern.

In the end, the `paste` creates the space-separated list from the newline-separated list produced by GNU `basename`.

Note that it would be difficult to parse the generated list of filenames if any of the original names of directories contain space characters.

Note that if the directory contains symbolic links, this method will try to follow those symbolic links.

---

Restricting us from using any external tools, we could use an array in the `bash` shell to store and manipulate the directory paths.

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob

topdir=/some/path

dirpaths=( "$topdir"/*/ )
dirpaths=( "${dirpaths[@]#$topdir/}" )
dirpaths=( "${dirpaths[@]%/}" )

printf '%s\n' "${dirpaths[*]}"
```

The above shell code expands the same globbing pattern as we used in the first part of this answer but stores the resulting directory paths in the array `dirpaths`.  It then deletes the known prefix `$topdir/` from each element of the array and the trailing `/` before printing the array as a single string of space-delimited names.  The delimiter used between the names on the last line will be the first character from `$IFS`, which by default is a space.

---

Using `find`, you could look for subdirectories in the particular top directory you're interested in while making sure not to return the top directory itself.  You would also stop `find` from progressing into the subdirectories.

```bsh
topdir=/some/path
find "${topdir%/}/." ! -name . -prune -type d -exec basename {} \; | paste -d ' ' -s -
```

The above command avoids the search starting point using a negated `-name` test, and it prunes the search tree with `-prune` so that `find` does not recurse down into any subdirectories. We call `basename` for each found directory which outputs the filename of the directories onto separate lines. As the last step, we're piping the result from `find` through `paste` to format the output into a space-separated list on a single line.

With GNU `find`, you could write this as

```bsh
find /some/path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | paste -d ' ' -s -
```

Using `find` like this will list directories with hidden names, and you will not see any symbolically linked directories.

---

In the `zsh` shell, you would be able to use a more advanced shell globbing pattern to pick out the filenames of only directories and print them in one go.

```bsh
print -r -- /some/path/*(/:t)
```

This command uses a glob qualifier, `/:t`, consisting of two parts, affecting the preceding globbing pattern `/some/path/*`.  The `/` makes the pattern only match directories (not symbolically linked ones; for that use `-/`), while `:t` extracts the "tail" of each generated pathname, i.e., the filename component.

The `print -r` command prints its arguments with spaces as delimiters while avoiding expanding escape sequences like `\n` or `\t` in the data. Using `--` to delimit the operands from the options (also works with `-` like in the `ksh` shell) makes sure directory names resulting from the glob expansion are not taken as options even if they start with `-`.

You could use this from within the `bash` shell to generate your list.

```bsh
zsh -c 'print -r -- /some/path/*(/:t)'
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ouch again. Yes, what you are proposing is far better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the directory from which you are listing the subdirectories, you can use the following ...

```
find /home/x/y -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P '
```

Comment: The command `ls -d *` will list files of all types, including directories.  It will not distinguish between directories and non-directories.

Comment: I see. I have replaced the command with the `find` command.

Comment: Note that `-printf` is only available in the GNU implementation of `find`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my suggestion using a `for` loop:

```
$ echo "$(for node in $(ls ~/); do if test -d "${node}"; then printf "${node} "; fi; done)"
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos
```

Alternate using `find`:

```
$ echo "$(for node in $(find ~/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do printf "$(basename ${node}) "; done)"
.mozilla Videos Pictures Music Documents Public Templates Downloads .gnupg .config .local .cache Desktop
```

**Edit:** In regards to [they](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/493832/they)'s comment, you would need to change the `IFS` variable for directories with spaces:

```
$ IFS_orig=${IFS}
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ echo "$(for node in $(ls ~/); do if test -d "${node}"; then printf "'${node}' "; fi; done)"
'Desktop' 'Documents' 'Downloads' 'Music' 'My Test' 'Pictures' 'Public' 'Templates' 'Videos'

$ IFS=${IFS_orig}
```

**Edit:** The simplest option seems to be to use `ls -d *`:

```
$ ls -d *
 Desktop   Documents   Downloads   Music  'My Test'   Pictures   Public   Templates   Videos
```

Also, forgot that in the `for` loops, should `test` using absolute or relative path:

```
$ echo "$(for node in $(ls "${HOME}"); do if test -d "${HOME}/${node}"; then printf "'${node}' "; fi; done)"
'Desktop' 'Documents' 'Downloads' 'Music' 'My Test' 'Pictures' 'Public' 'Templates' 'Videos'
```

Comment: Add a directory called `My Documents` and see what happens. The issue is that the shell will split the output from the command substitution around `ls` into words based on spaces, tabs, and newlines.  The loop will iterate over each of the words that this generates. The shell would also apply filename globbing on any term that happened to look like a globbing pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer in regards to whitespace. Not sure what to do about globbing patterns.

Comment: I don't want to be a party pooper, but Unix filenames could theoretically contain newlines too. Also, I now see that you test with `test -d` on `$node` whether it's a directory in the current directory.  Doing so will likely fail if there isn't a set of identically named directories in the current directory.  You also have an issue with `printf`, which disqualifies some filenames containing the character `%` (introducing a `printf` formatting sequence). The `printf` utility's first argument should always be a static formatting string, so use `printf '"%s" ' "$node"` instead.

Comment: Your approach with `find` is saner but still suffers from issues with `printf`.  With GNU `find`, you could use something like `find ~/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | paste -d ' ' -s -` instead.  Note that we don't need those command substitutions. With non-GNU `find`, replace `-printf '%f\n'` with `-exec basename {} \;`.

Answer (score -2):

The final command I got to is: `ls -d ~/y/*/ | awk -F/ '{print$5}' | sed 's/ /\\ /' | tr '\n' ' '`

Origin was from a user who has now deleted their post, but they didn't account for not using ls on the current directory, so I adjusted for that. I also added the sed pipe so it adds backslashes for directory names' which have spaces in them.

It is pretty hardcoded with `print$5` so it'll only work with directories right in the `~` directory.

Comment: You should use `find ~/y/ -maxdepth 1 -type d` for this, not `ls`.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).   Spaces and newlines are valid characters in filenames, so spaces are not a reliable filename separator.  In fact, he only reliable separator character is a NUL (because it **isn't** valid in a filename), so you should use `-print0` with the `find` command, and pipe it into programs which can work with NUL-separated input.  or use `mapfile` to read it into an array.

Comment: Your question is how to `ls` subdirectories this way, i.e. general use of `ls`. If this only works in directories in `/~`, it's not a general answer but for a specific case. Before you accept it, I'd suggest either editing the command so that it works also outside `/~`, or changing your question and title to also refer to this one specific use case.